# Format numbers In a DataFrame conditional on their value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, format

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': [1000, 2, 3, 2400000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which results in

```
col1
1000
2
3
2400000
```

Suppose I would like to have this DataFrame formatting in thousands or millions, depending on the current value, how would I do this?
Say I would like the result to be

```
col1
1K
2
3
2.4M
```

I know how to do it when I'd like the whole column to be formatting into millions or thousands, but not when it comes to separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579310/formatting-long-numbers-as-strings-in-python) in `apply`.

```
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(lambda x: human_format(x))
df.col1
0    1.00K
1    1.23K
2     2.00
3     3.00
4    2.40M
```

*Optional - You can further remove `.00` after this step.*