# How to format float values in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to format float values in my django template like this:

`125000` => `125k`

`125,000,000` => `125M`

Do I have to use any `custom template tag` for this or django already has one?

Any idea?

Comment: Look at [django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/humanize/), probably not exactly what you need, but that gives you an idea how to write your own filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that by the below filter template tag:

```
@register.filter
def format_number(num):
    num = int(num)
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '%.2f%s' % (num, ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P'][magnitude])

print(format_number(32413423)) # 32.41M
```

It is going to support to `P`

I've created the code using this link:
[formatting long numbers as strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579310/formatting-long-numbers-as-strings-in-python)

Comment: when copy pasting other peoples code/answers please read the comments and inform the people about potential bugs or link the original answer

Comment: Getting this error now `bad operand type for abs(): 'SafeText'`

Comment: @NiladryKar I think maybe you are passing the argument as a string. you can convert it in your function to int to work. e.g: 
    num = int(num) // add this line to the first line after the definition of format_number function

Comment: @NiladryKar I've added this line to my post too

Comment: Actually I am trying to do this for a float value...The above solution is for `int` value. It works using `float(num)`

Comment: @NiladryKar Aha, you're right. You need the float one. great

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/) is the list of built-in template tags and filters so if it's not there, you have to build your own.

You'll find something similar to what you need in [django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/humanize/), use this as the basis to build your own filter.