# Formatting string width with f-strings

Tags: python, f-string

I'm trying to create headers of a given width and would like to use

```
>>> print(f'{"string":15<}|')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code '<' for object of type 'str'
```

Are we meant to cobble together headers like this or am I missing something about f strings?

```
print('string'+" "*(15-len('string'))+"|")
string         |
```

Comment: No.  The real answer is that I screwed up the operator. It's <15 not 15<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the Python [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), alignment specifiers (e.g. `<`)  must precede the width specifier (e.g. `15`). With this criteria in mind, the correct formulation for your format string is `{:<15}`. However, left-alignment is inferred by default for strings, so you can write this simply as `{:15}`.

```
>>> print(f'{"string":<15}|')
string         |
>>> print(f'{"string":15}|')
string         |
```

Comment: Yes. I had the < in the wrong place.  But I see the simple number is better.

Comment: print(f'{"123456":<15}k') how can i make this print 123 k?

Comment: @vanetoj See [Formatting long numbers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/579310/11082165)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is simply `print(f'{"string":15}|')`