# Changing x ticks labels iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change the format of my x ticks labels. They are generated thanks to :

```
range = pd.cut(df['Notional EUR'],
                   bins=[0, 250000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000, 100000000, 500000000])
range = range.value_counts(sort=False)
range = range.to_frame()
range.columns = ["Effectif"]
chart = sns.barplot(data=range,
                    color = '#F80116',
                    x=range.index.values,
                    y="Effectif")
```

I would like to format it as follow : `(0, 250K]` instead of `(0, 250000]`.
I tried several ways such as : `xlabels = [f'({l:.2f}, {r:.2f}]'+'K' for l, r in chart.get_xticks()/1000]` but without success...

Here is the chart concerned :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's your plotting code? Generally you can use `ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)`

Comment: I've added it in the question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *all* labels to be abbreviated as `K` (including like `5000K`), replace all `000([\]\),])` patterns with `K\1`:

```py
xticklabels = [re.sub(r'000([\]\),])', r'K\1', label.get_text()) for label in chart.get_xticklabels()]
chart.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

[image: xticklabels as K]

If you want the labels to be abbreviated adaptively (`K`, `M`, etc.), you can use something like [this **`human_format()`** function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955617/13138364):

```py
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955617/13138364
def human_format(match):
    num = int(match.group(0))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num = round(num / 1000.0)
    abbr = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P'][magnitude]
    return f'{num:.0f}{abbr}'

xticklabels = [re.sub(r'([0-9]+)', human_format, label.get_text()) for label in chart.get_xticklabels()]
chart.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

[image: xticklabels abbreviated adaptively]