# How to convert number to compact format in python for charting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How to convert number to compact format for better visualization in graphs?

Numbers are coming from a series.

This is my annotation code:

```
for x, y in zip(t2.index,t2):
    label="{:.0f}".format(y)
    plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 ha='center')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `matplotlib`, but i'm guessing you could use scientific notation or things like `10M`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you could use either scientific notation:

```py
label = f'{y:.1e}' # 13236334 -> 1.3e+07
```

Or human format:

```py
label = human_format(y) # 13236334 -> 13.2M
```

Where [**`human_format()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955617/13138364) is something like this:

```py
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955617/13138364
def human_format(num, round_to=1):
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num = round(num / 1000.0, round_to)
        abbr = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P'][magnitude]
    return f'{num:.{round_to}f}{abbr}'
```