# how to format big numbers to form of thousands in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

[image]

As you can see the numbers are big , i want to make these numbers in thousands, for example i wanna make 164,416 as 164k to all the numbers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this solves half of your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579310/formatting-long-numbers-as-strings/45846841#45846841