# Plotly - set decimal place in choropleth

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, visualization, choropleth

How do you convert number 1.425887B to 1.4 in plotly choropleth ?

```
data2022 = dict(type = 'choropleth',
            colorscale = 'agsunset',
            reversescale = True,
            locations = df['Country/Territory'],
            locationmode = 'country names',
            z = df['2022 Population'],
            text = df['CCA3'    ],
            marker = dict(line = dict(color = 'rgb(12, 12, 12)', width=1)),
            colorbar = {'title': 'Population'})

layout2022 = dict(title = '<b>World Population 2022<b>',
               geo = dict(showframe = True,
                          showland = True, landcolor = 'rgb(198, 197, 198)',
                          showlakes = True, lakecolor = 'rgb(85, 173, 240)',
                          showrivers = True, rivercolor = 'rgb(173, 216, 230)', 
                          showocean = True, oceancolor = 'rgb(173, 216, 230)',
                          projection = {'type': 'natural earth'}))

choromap2022 = go.Figure(data=[data2022], layout=layout2022) 

choromap2022.update_geos(lataxis_showgrid = True, lonaxis_showgrid = True)

choromap2022.update_layout(height = 600,
                       title_x = 0.5, 
                       title_font_color = 'red',
                       title_font_family = 'Times New Roman',
                       title_font_size = 30,
                       margin=dict(t=80, r=50,  l=50))

iplot(choromap2022)
```

[This is the image of the result I got, I want to convert the population of China from 1.425887B to 1.4B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LZ2z.png)

I try to look up on the plotly document but cannot find anything.

This is the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

````
 'CCA3': {0: 'AFG', 1: 'ALB', 2: 'DZA', 3: 'ASM', 4: 'AND'},
 'Country/Territory': {0: 'Afghanistan',
  1: 'Albania',
  2: 'Algeria',
  3: 'American Samoa',
  4: 'Andorra'},
 'Capital': {0: 'Kabul',
  1: 'Tirana',
  2: 'Algiers',
  3: 'Pago Pago',
  4: 'Andorra la Vella'},
 'Continent': {0: 'Asia', 1: 'Europe', 2: 'Africa', 3: 'Oceania', 4: 'Europe'},
 '2022 Population': {0: 41128771, 1: 2842321, 2: 44903225, 3: 44273, 4: 79824},
 '2020 Population': {0: 38972230, 1: 2866849, 2: 43451666, 3: 46189, 4: 77700},
 '2015 Population': {0: 33753499, 1: 2882481, 2: 39543154, 3: 51368, 4: 71746},
 '2010 Population': {0: 28189672, 1: 2913399, 2: 35856344, 3: 54849, 4: 71519},
 '2000 Population': {0: 19542982, 1: 3182021, 2: 30774621, 3: 58230, 4: 66097},
 '1990 Population': {0: 10694796, 1: 3295066, 2: 25518074, 3: 47818, 4: 53569},
 '1980 Population': {0: 12486631, 1: 2941651, 2: 18739378, 3: 32886, 4: 35611},
 '1970 Population': {0: 10752971, 1: 2324731, 2: 13795915, 3: 27075, 4: 19860},
 'Area (km²)': {0: 652230, 1: 28748, 2: 2381741, 3: 199, 4: 468},
 'Density (per km²)': {0: 63.0587,
  1: 98.8702,
  2: 18.8531,
  3: 222.4774,
  4: 170.5641},
 'Growth Rate': {0: 1.0257, 1: 0.9957, 2: 1.0164, 3: 0.9831, 4: 1.01},
 'World Population Percentage': {0: 0.52, 1: 0.04, 2: 0.56, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}}```
````

Comment: where is the number appearing? do you mean in the `hovertext`? an image of your output showing where the number is appearing with `4,700,000,000` would be helpful. also a sample dataframe would be helpful too – can you copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question? thank you

Comment: @DerekO, hi thanks for replying, I just edited the question and added more information, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trickier than it appears because plotly uses [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format), but I believe they are using additional metric abbreviations in their formatting to have the default display numbers larger than 1000 in the format `1.425887B`.

My original idea was to round to the nearest 2 digits in the `hovertemplate` with something like:

```
data2022 = dict(..., hovertemplate = "%{z:.2r}<br>%{text}<extra></extra>")
```

However, this removes the default metric abbreviation and causes the entire long form decimal to display. The population of China should show up as `1400000000` instead of `1.4B`.

So one possible workaround would be to create a new column in your DataFrame called `"2022 Population Text"` and format the number using a custom function to round and abbreviate your number (credit goes to @rtaft for [their function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846841/5327068) which does exactly that). Then you can pass this column to `customdata`, and display customdata in your hovertemplate (instead of z).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data =  {'CCA3': {0: 'AFG', 1: 'ALB', 2: 'DZA', 3: 'ASM', 4: 'AND'},
 'Country/Territory': {0: 'Afghanistan',
  1: 'Albania',
  2: 'Algeria',
  3: 'American Samoa',
  4: 'Andorra'},
 'Capital': {0: 'Kabul',
  1: 'Tirana',
  2: 'Algiers',
  3: 'Pago Pago',
  4: 'Andorra la Vella'},
 'Continent': {0: 'Asia', 1: 'Europe', 2: 'Africa', 3: 'Oceania', 4: 'Europe'},
 '2022 Population': {0: 1412000000, 1: 2842321, 2: 44903225, 3: 44273, 4: 79824},
 '2020 Population': {0: 38972230, 1: 2866849, 2: 43451666, 3: 46189, 4: 77700},
 '2015 Population': {0: 33753499, 1: 2882481, 2: 39543154, 3: 51368, 4: 71746},
 '2010 Population': {0: 28189672, 1: 2913399, 2: 35856344, 3: 54849, 4: 71519},
 '2000 Population': {0: 19542982, 1: 3182021, 2: 30774621, 3: 58230, 4: 66097},
 '1990 Population': {0: 10694796, 1: 3295066, 2: 25518074, 3: 47818, 4: 53569},
 '1980 Population': {0: 12486631, 1: 2941651, 2: 18739378, 3: 32886, 4: 35611},
 '1970 Population': {0: 10752971, 1: 2324731, 2: 13795915, 3: 27075, 4: 19860},
 'Area (km²)': {0: 652230, 1: 28748, 2: 2381741, 3: 199, 4: 468},
 'Density (per km²)': {0: 63.0587,
  1: 98.8702,
  2: 18.8531,
  3: 222.4774,
  4: 170.5641},
 'Growth Rate': {0: 1.0257, 1: 0.9957, 2: 1.0164, 3: 0.9831, 4: 1.01},
 'World Population Percentage': {0: 0.52, 1: 0.04, 2: 0.56, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}
}

## rounds a number to the specified precision, and adds metrics abbreviations
## i.e. 14230000000 --> 14B
## reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846841/5327068
def human_format(num):
    num = float('{:.2g}'.format(num))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '{}{}'.format('{:f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['2022 Population Text'] = df['2022 Population'].apply(lambda x: human_format(x))

data2022 = dict(type = 'choropleth',
            colorscale = 'agsunset',
            reversescale = True,
            locations = df['Country/Territory'],
            locationmode = 'country names',
            z = df['2022 Population'],
            text = df['CCA3'],
            customdata = df['2022 Population Text'],
            marker = dict(line = dict(color = 'rgb(12, 12, 12)', width=1)),
            colorbar = {'title': 'Population'},
            hovertemplate = "%{customdata}<br>%{text}<extra></extra>"
            )

layout2022 = dict(title = '<b>World Population 2022<b>',
               geo = dict(showframe = True,
                          showland = True, landcolor = 'rgb(198, 197, 198)',
                          showlakes = True, lakecolor = 'rgb(85, 173, 240)',
                          showrivers = True, rivercolor = 'rgb(173, 216, 230)', 
                          showocean = True, oceancolor = 'rgb(173, 216, 230)',
                          projection = {'type': 'natural earth'}))

choromap2022 = go.Figure(data=[data2022], layout=layout2022) 

choromap2022.update_geos(lataxis_showgrid = True, lonaxis_showgrid = True)

choromap2022.update_layout(height = 600,
                       title_x = 0.5, 
                       title_font_color = 'red',
                       title_font_family = 'Times New Roman',
                       title_font_size = 30,
                       margin=dict(t=80, r=50,  l=50),
                       )

choromap2022.show()
```

Note: Since China wasn't included in your sample data, I changed the population of `AFG` to `1412000000` to test that the hovertemplate would display it as `'1.4B'`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Derek, I really appreciated, this helps me a lot. I have one more question, do format ```1412000000``` and display it as ```1.4B``` is a good way and keep information concise, or should I keep it as default ?

Comment: @ĐạtDương that is your choice – I think it's a good way to keep it concise because `1.4B` will be quickly understood by everyone, but `1412000000` requires people to count the number of digits. you could add commas so that it is formatted `1,412,000,000` but it also just takes up more room and I think `1.4B` looks better in the hover